# Regex for capturing data after slash?

Tags: asp.net, regex

How to capture data after slash by using `Regex`?

for ex: `Z0789/H76345`

here, I want to capture only `H76345` from above example.

Comment: Split using `/`  and get second part

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Simply use `\/(.*)$`

Comment: if you want to get the data after the last '/' you can use the following code

var data=Z0789/H76345;
lastdata = data.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1];

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regex to capture suffixes after a specific character: use `LastIndexOf` to find the position, add 1, and take `Substring`, like this:

```
var s = "Z0789/H76345";
var res = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2VJ1a9)

Note that this trick works even for strings that do not have a slash, because -1 returned by `LastIndexOf` is countered by +1 in the expression, producing zero.